# Why can't the smoke monster get over the fences?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost

In S03E12 of *Lost*, "Par Avion", Kate, Locke, Sayid and Danielle bypassed a sonic fence by going over it using a tree.

[image]

But in S03E15, "Left Behind", the smoke monster is not able to bypass it. It tried to go through it but is not going over it. Is this a loophole in the script?

[image]

There have been many instances when smoke monster penetrated ground, uprooted trees from deep underground and also flew to tree heights which is more than sonic fences.

Why didn't the smoke monster try to go over it? It was such an obvious way to bypass it, because it has the ability to fly and also go underground.

Comment: There’s a lot of fan theories out there, but a pod cast with the producers confirmed that the smoke monster can’t leave the ground (fly), for the same reason he can’t just hover over the ocean and leave, he’s connected to the island, so he can’t fly away. So being stuck to the ground, means he can’t penetrate the sonic barrier.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan: Added some info to question after comments. Please check.

Comment: It can bypass it underground, if there is a path for that. Ben did a trick that opened that path, in order to cast it into the village.

Answer (score 2):

Though you will never find a canon answer that admits this, this was a loophole in the script.  The monster can hover, or at least "stand on its legs" and appear to be very tall and menacing, and has done so in several episodes.  It also doesn't act like "dry ice smoke", it is clearly seen in several episodes hovering completely above the ground.

With those 2 solid bits of reality, there is no reason the smoke monster couldn't "inchworm" over the sonic barrier.  Raise up, reach over, touch the ground on the other side, and then have its backside do the same while its frontside was firmly planted on the ground, if indeed it couldn't completely leave the ground.

Comment: Exactly my point.